# Calculating var by year to plot geom_line()

Tags: r, ggplot2, tidyverse

I have a dataset with a bunch of observations by year. I just want to calculate percentages of "fail" and "attend", by year, and then plot the yearly trends with `geom_line()` together on the same plot. I got started with the code below but it's not quite right--it needs to be collapsed by year, I think?

Code:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  mutate(perc_fail = fail/sum(fail),
         perc_attend = attend/sum(attend)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = year)) +
  geom_line()
```

Data:

```
df < -structure(list(year = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("2000", "2001", "2002", "2003"
), class = "factor"), fail = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), attend = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, -60L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `summarise()` rather than `mutate()` to get a single value per year and then plot.  Note that when you're plotting different series from different variables, you can put the label you want in the legend in the aesthetic (as I did for colour in both `geom_line()` calls.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(perc_fail = mean(fail),
         perc_attend = mean(attend)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = year, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= perc_fail, colour="Fail")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=perc_attend, colour="Attend")) + 
  labs(y="Percent", 
       x="Year", 
       colour ="") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=~scales::percent(.x))
```

[image]

You could also pivot the data to long format and use `state_summary()` to generate the summary statistics for you.  The code below will produce the same graph.

```r
df %>% 
  mutate(year = as.numeric(as.character(year))) %>% 
  pivot_longer(c("fail", "attend"), names_to="status", values_to = "vals") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x=year, y = vals, colour=status)) + 
  stat_summary(fun = mean, geom="line") +  
  labs(y="Percent", 
       x="Year", 
       colour ="") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=~scales::percent(.x))
```