# Hiding "20" of year "20XX" when displaying axis ticks ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Okay, borrowing same data (and still making same figure) as my earlier question ([Calculating var by year to plot geom_line()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75417332/calculating-var-by-year-to-plot-geom-line/75417364#75417364)), in my real data I have years 2000-2017, so the X axis gets pretty crowded.

But there's no way to cut out one evenly with that range (can't do every other or every third and have it break evenly).

So I'm thinking I'd like to cut out the "20" from "20XX" when displaying the 'year' variable along the x axis (so would just be 02, 03, 04, etc). Anyone have a neat trick for doing that? I tried creating a new factor variable that was just "year - 2000", so "02", "03", etc. but then it doesn't retain or display the leading 0.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ggplot2)

df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(perc_fail = mean(fail),
         perc_attend = mean(attend)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = year, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= perc_fail, colour="Fail")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=perc_attend, colour="Attend")) + 
  labs(y="Percent", 
       x="Year", 
       colour ="") + 
  scale_y_continuous(labels=~scales::percent(.x))
```

Data:

```
structure(list(year = c(2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 
2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2000, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 
2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2001, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 
2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2002, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 
2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003, 2003), fail = c(0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 
0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0), attend = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)), row.names = c(NA, 
-60L), spec = structure(list(cols = list(year = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), fail = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector")), attend = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double", 
"collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess", 
"collector")), delim = ","), class = "col_spec"), problems = <pointer: 0x0000025df802ece0>, class = c("spec_tbl_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may add

```
 ... + 
 scale_x_continuous(labels = ~ substr(.x, 3, 4))
```

-output

[image]

Answer (score 2):

An alternative way is to add a label column:

```
df %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(perc_fail = mean(fail),
            perc_attend = mean(attend)) %>% 
  mutate(label_year = sprintf("%02d", year %% 100)) %>% 
  ggplot(., aes(x = label_year, group=1)) +
  geom_line(aes(y= perc_fail, colour="Fail")) + 
  geom_line(aes(y=perc_attend, colour="Attend")) + 
  labs(y="Percent", 
       x="Year", 
       colour ="")
```

[image]